# Вот 89603408610 билайн наличные мне кинь на баланс - What is the meaning?

Tags: выражения

I am very new in Russian language. I would like to know the meaning of the following sentence:

> Вот 89603408610 билайн наличные мне кинь на баланс.

Thanks

Comment: It is a common scam. Don't reply. Don't send any money.

Comment: Yes, I think so. At first, they talk like normal people. After some time, they ask money to me. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can only interpret it as an order or command (due to absence of any terms of politeness) to add funds to a particular phone (identified by the number) on a particular cellular carrier ("билайн").

Literally translated it would be

> Here it is: NNNNN on "*билайн*", drop some cash for me on that account.

The punctuation is probably omitted for brevity ("*txtspk*").

Comment: Dear friend, thank you for your kind reply. I fully understood about the sentence.

Comment: @user907860, I am also new to this site. I just found the 'accept button' left side. I did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is improper, broken Russian, probably because it is an SMS text.

Билайн is a Russian mobile phone company.
89603408610 is probably a phone number.
One asks or requests to add money to his phone account.